# Android: Add Facebook & Twitter Account in FourSquare

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, foursquare

[image]

In above picture there's facebookPermissions and sendToFacebook JSON tags and here is the [[link]](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=settings/all). In your FourSquare account there's a **Setting->Sharing with Other Network** option.

How can i add that facebook and twitter account through my application so that it will update automatically in my account settings.

Suggest some peace of code or tutorial.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in your question? Can you give an example of the behavior you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes @octopi. In my application i am able to fetch sendToFaceBook tag and check whether its true or false. But if **sendToFacebook** false then how can i set it to true and fetch all permission, place in **facebookPermissions** tag. Have you any idea about that? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This isn't possible via the API. The only settings a 3rd party app is allowed to set is documented here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/settings/set

Comment: You are right @octopi. By using Facebook SDK, i have user's facebook user-name and all permissions that mention in above screen shot. Now i have no idea to set setting(post) attribute. Can you please give me sample code to perform this task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Foursquare API is RESTful, so all you need to do is make an HTTP POST request to the endpoint with the appropriate params. For example, to push a user's badges to Twitter, just make a POST request to `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/settings/sendBadgesToTwitter/set?value=1`. You can always use an Android library as well: https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries